# Unable to use JWT for authentication in influxdb using C#

Tags: c#, token, influxdb, jwt

I have tested that my token works via curl:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:8086/query?db=test2&q=show%20databases" --header "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkbWluMSIsImV4cCI6MTYzNDQyODgwMH0.1EzM01okZBuxDe_7V4VUvVUgyHkPiCCph1nysBLFpB0"
```

Output:

```
{"results":[{"statement_id":0,"series":[{"name":"databases","columns":["name"],"values":[["_internal"],["test2"]]}]}]}
```

But when I try to use the same token in my code I get:

```
InfluxDB.Client.Core.Exceptions.HttpException: '{"error":"unable to parse authentication credentials"}
```

Here is the code:

```
var influxDBClient = InfluxDBClientFactory.Create("http://localhost:8086", "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkbWluMSIsImV4cCI6MTYzNDQyODgwMH0.1EzM01okZBuxDe_7V4VUvVUgyHkPiCCph1nysBLFpB0".ToCharArray());

               var flux = "from(bucket:\"test2\") |> range(start: 0)";

                var fluxTables = await influxDBClient.GetQueryApi().QueryAsync(flux, "org_id"); // This is where I get the error
                fluxTables.ForEach(fluxTable =>
                {
                    var fluxRecords = fluxTable.Records;
                    fluxRecords.ForEach(fluxRecord =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{fluxRecord.GetTime()}: {fluxRecord.GetValue()}");
                    });
                });

                influxDBClient.Dispose();
```

I tried using it as a string (without converting it to a char array) and I got the same error. I tried adding `"Authorization: Bearer "` at the start of the token but the error persisted. When I use
`var influxDBClient = InfluxDBClientFactory.Create("http://localhost:8086",  "admin1", "*snip*".ToCharArray());` it doesn't work either. Any help will be appreciated.

P.S.: I'm on Windows, if that matters, and using Influxdb version 1.8.3-1.

Comment: Authentication is done using TLS.  The default TLS version in Curl and c# is probably different.  TLS 1.0/1.1 not longer works and you must use TLS 1.2/1.3.  You can verify the TLS version with a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64375532/ssis-c-sharp-http-getasync-not-waiting-for-the-response#comment113835214_64375532

Comment: @jdweng I don't quite understand; I thought I was using plain http(?) The Wireshark capture makes no mention of TLS.

Comment: Some server will refuse non secure connections.  Best thing to do is to compare working curl with non working c#.  Check TLS versions and check headers in first request.  then make c# look like the working curl.

Comment: @jdweng thanks for your input. I ended up using a different library. An interesting thing I didn't mention was that Wireshark showed I was getting a 404 answer to the POST request sent by my authentication code and then a subsequent 401 for the query.

Comment: The 404 was not found.  So it is possible initially the connection was attempted with HTTP and failed with 404 and then a retry was automatically done with https and then you got 401.