# Microsoft Graph API beta phone Authentication update fails from c# web api method

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api, beta-versions

Using Microsoft graph API i am able to update the phone authentication method section with mobile number using PostMan tool.

Based the approach i have created a Web API method that has to update the phone authentication method section with mobile number for the user. But fails with error

> The user is unauthenticated

This is to have the MFA where-in user is expected to input the one time passcode sent to the given mobile number.

The code i have written is:

```
>     using System;
>     using System.Collections.Generic;
>     using System.Net.Http.Headers;
>     using System.Threading.Tasks;
>     
>     using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
>     using Microsoft.Graph;
>     using Microsoft.Graph.Auth;
>     using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
>     
>     using UseGraphAPI.Interfaces;
>     using UseGraphAPI.Models;
>     
>     namespace UseGraphAPI.Repository
>     {
>         public class UserManager : IUserManager
>         {
>             private readonly GraphServiceClient graphClient;
>             private readonly B2CUserSettings userSettings;
>             private readonly AuthenticationResult token;
>     
>             public UserManager(IOptions<B2CUserSettings> userSettings)
>             {
>                 // The client_id, client_secret, and tenant are pulled in from the appsettings.json from coach API
>                 this.userSettings = userSettings.Value;
>     
>                 // Initialize the client credential auth provider
>                 IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
>                     .Create(this.userSettings.Clientid)
>                     .WithTenantId(this.userSettings.Tenant)
>                     .WithClientSecret(this.userSettings.Clientsecret)
>                     //.WithRedirectUri("http://localhost:62569")
>                     //.WithAuthority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/29fdf6e9-53c9-4bc7-8927-fa50e62019bc/v2.0")
>                     .Build();
>     
>                 ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
>     
>                 // Set up the Microsoft Graph service client with client credentials
>                 GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
>     
>                 //string[] scopes = new string[] {
>                 //    "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
>                 //};
>     
>                 //token = confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync().Result;
>                 //GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta", 
>                 //    new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async(requestMessage) => 
>                 //    {
>                 //    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token.AccessToken);
>                 //    }));
>     
>                 this.graphClient = graphClient;
>             }
>     
>             public async Task UpdateUserPhoneMethod(B2CUserPhoneAuth b2CUserPhoneAuth)
>             {
>                 var user = await GetUserByEmail(b2CUserPhoneAuth.Email);
>                 var userId = user.CurrentPage[0].Id;
>     
>                 try
>                 {
>                     PhoneAuthenticationMethod phoneAuthenticationMethod = new PhoneAuthenticationMethod()
>                     {
>                         PhoneNumber = b2CUserPhoneAuth.PhoneNumber,
>                         PhoneType = AuthenticationPhoneType.Mobile
>                     };
>     
>                     await graphClient.Users[userId].Authentication.PhoneMethods
>                         .Request()
>                         .AddAsync(phoneAuthenticationMethod);
>                 }
>                 catch (Exception ex)
>                 {
>                     throw ex;
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
```

The permissions given on the application that is registered in Azure are:

> Directory.AccessAsUser.All (Delegated) Directory.ReadWrite.All
> (Delegated & Application) Policy.Read.All (Delegated)
> Policy.ReadWrite.AuthenticationMethod (Delegated) User.ReadWrite.All
> (Delegated & Application) UserAuthenticationMethod.ReadWrite.All
> (Delegated & Application)

Please review and let me know if there is something missing in my code or permissions.

The requirement is to create user and add mobile phone with SMS signin flag to true.

regards,

Arjuna

Comment: `ClientCredentialProvider` use application permission, but the API doesn't support application permission, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/phoneauthenticationmethod-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#permissions). You could only use the delegate permission as the doc shows.

Comment: See my responses at following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64375532/ssis-c-sharp-http-getasync-not-waiting-for-the-response#comment113835214_64375532

Comment: @jdweng,  I saw your posted URL and found it is using HttpClient.  But if you see my code i am using the MS graph API beta version which does'nt have the option.  Can you suggest if there is a way that can be achieved in my code.

Comment: Read notes on following page : https://github.com/microsoftgraph/uwp-csharp-connect-sample

Comment: @jdweng, I verified trying out your option before this line of code

await graphClient.Users[userId].Authentication.PhoneMethods
                    .Request()
                    .AddAsync(phoneAuthenticationMethod);


it throws the below error

Code: unauthenticated
Message: The user is unauthenticated.
Inner error:
 Message: The user is unauthenticated.
AdditionalData:
 date: 2020-10-19T10:16:41
 request-id: 904355cc-df61-4428-89dc-b8dc08b27646
 client-request-id: 904355cc-df61-4428-89dc-b8dc08b27646
ClientRequestId: 904355cc-df61-4428-89dc-b8dc08b27646

Comment: @PamelaPeng, the same delegate permission works fine if i am updating the data using Post Man?  Why it is allowing postman to update and why not from web api method?  Can you put some light on this point.

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare headers in the first request.  The default headers in c# are different from Postman.  Modify the headers in c# to match Postman.  Often this is due to the User Agent.

Comment: If it works for you in POSTMAN, then i would try to do match the headers/values in C# code as well.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment, the code `ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);` is based on client credential flow with application permission. But the [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/phoneauthenticationmethod-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#permissions) only supports delegate permission.

You could use other methods(eg.[**AuthorizationCodeProvider**](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-auth#a-authorization-code-provider)) instead of it.

```
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(clientId)
                .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret) // or .WithCertificate(certificate)
                .Build();

AuthorizationCodeProvider authenticationProvider = new AuthorizationCodeProvider(confidentialClientApplication, scopes);
```