# HttpClientHandler UseDefaultCredentials in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, http, .net-core, console-application

With the following running in a **.NET Framework 4.7.2** Console application and `some_url` pointing to a server in my Windows network that uses Kerberos, I get a HTTP code of **200** back:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler { UseDefaultCredentials = true };
var client = new HttpClient(handler);

var code = client.GetAsync(some_url).Result.StatusCode
```

but using the same code in a **.NET Core 3.1** application gives a **401** instead. This is the same as I get when running in **.NET Framework 4.7.2** but not setting `UseDefaultCredentials` to `true`, leading me to believe the **.NET Core 3.1** version does not pass the credentials along.

What do I need to do to get a **.NET Core 3.1** application to pass the current credentials?
I've tried playing around with setting the `Credentials` on the `handler` to an instance of `NetworkCredential` but to no avail.

Comment: AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.UseSocketsHttpHandler", false);

Comment: Five years ago the industry decided to eliminate TLS 1.0/1.1 which is used for authentication due to security issues.  In June this year Microsoft did a push which disabled TLS 1.0/1.1 on servers and now client must use TLS 1.2/1.3.  Now depending if your code set the TLS version of just used default are part of the issue.  The default TLS version depends on a lot of things 1) Your operating System 2) The version of Net 3) Your user IE settings. If you really want to see what is happening use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and check version of TLS with each of your combinations.

Comment: @jdweng this issue is about kerberos auth, not TLS

Comment: Did you tried my solution? By default dotnet core using new implementation of handler and framework using httpsys... New implementation doesn't suport NTLM/Kerberos

Comment: Are you using HTTP or HTTPS?  HTTPS will automatically use TLS.

Comment: @Selvin I am setting the `handler` explicitly to the `HttpClientHandler` so setting the parameter you suggest does not have an impact.

Comment: @jdweng I am using https, but my main concern is why it works in .NET Framework but not .NET Core.

Comment: Is has to do with the TLS version.   Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and check TLS version.  Does your code specify TLS version of are you using Default settings?  The default TLS setting depend on a few issues 1) Operating System 2) Version of Net 3) User Web settings

Comment: @jdweng I understand that it depends on these thing, but my question is more about how I get the .NET Core version to do the same as the .NET Framework version does.

Comment: It is not a CORE vs Net issue!!!  It is the default TLS version.  For the past two months I've being helping people three times a day with this issue.  See my response at following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64375532/ssis-c-sharp-http-getasync-not-waiting-for-the-response#comment113835214_64375532

Comment: @jdweng I have tried setting the TLS version on the `ServicePointManager`, I apologise for not including that in my question. It does not help for this.

Comment: Use a sniffer.  Compare the TLS version and headers in first request between working and non working.

Comment: This has nothing to do with TLS, see @Selvin's comment. did you try that (best in the Main() method)?

Comment: @Martin Ullrich Yes, I tried that.

Comment: No. It has nothing to do with TLS. I checked this first. The answer below from Toko works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should change AllowAutoRedirect to false and loop over the response message

```
HttpResponseMessage httpResponse;
do
{
   httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
   if (httpResponse.Headers.Contains("Location"))
   {
       //Find the redirection address
        uri = httpResponse.Headers.Location.OriginalString;
   }
   else
   {
       throw new ApplicationException("No Location header found in web response");
   }
 } while (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Redirect);
```

Comment: Thank you. That helps. I saw in wireshark some redirects working without setting AllowRedirect = false, but seems not all. With your solution it works. I only had to add `RedirectMethod' in the while condition.