# OPC UA Server failed to start due exception: Cannot access certificate private key

Tags: c#, opc-ua

My OPC UA Server fails to start due Cannot access certificate private key exception. It really confuse me, because I'm using AnonymousUserTokenPolicy. Last time I have run server, it was all ok. I didn't change config file neither relevant code. I have been searching on OPCFoundation with no success.

this is my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationConfiguration
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:ua="http://opcfoundation.org/UA/2008/02/Types.xsd"
  xmlns="http://opcfoundation.org/UA/SDK/Configuration.xsd">
  
  <ApplicationName>RoboBar.TestServer</ApplicationName>
  <ApplicationUri>urn:localhost:RoboBar.TestServer</ApplicationUri>
  <ProductUri>https://github.com/testbedCIIRC/RoboBar-Server</ProductUri>
  <ApplicationType>Server_0</ApplicationType>
  
  <SecurityConfiguration>

    <!-- Where the application instance certificate is stored (MachineDefault) -->
    <ApplicationCertificate>
      <StoreType>Directory</StoreType>
      <StorePath>%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\MachineDefault</StorePath>
      <SubjectName>RoboBar.TestServer</SubjectName>
    </ApplicationCertificate>

    <!-- Where the issuer certificate are stored (certificate authorities) -->
    <TrustedIssuerCertificates>
      <StoreType>Directory</StoreType>
      <StorePath>%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\UA Certificate Authorities</StorePath>
    </TrustedIssuerCertificates>

    <!-- Where the trust list is stored (UA Applications) -->
    <TrustedPeerCertificates>
      <StoreType>Directory</StoreType>
      <StorePath>%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\UA Applications</StorePath>
    </TrustedPeerCertificates>

    <!-- The directory used to store invalid certficates for later review by the administrator. -->
    <RejectedCertificateStore>
      <StoreType>Directory</StoreType>
      <StorePath>%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\RejectedCertificates</StorePath>
    </RejectedCertificateStore>

    <!-- WARNING: The following setting (to automatically accept untrusted certificates) should be used
    for easy debugging purposes ONLY and turned off for production deployments! -->
    <AutoAcceptUntrustedCertificates>true</AutoAcceptUntrustedCertificates>
  
  </SecurityConfiguration>
  
  <TransportConfigurations></TransportConfigurations>
  <TransportQuotas>
    <OperationTimeout>600000</OperationTimeout>
    <MaxStringLength>1048576</MaxStringLength>
    <MaxByteStringLength>1048576</MaxByteStringLength>
    <MaxArrayLength>65535</MaxArrayLength>
    <MaxMessageSize>4194304</MaxMessageSize>
    <MaxBufferSize>65535</MaxBufferSize>
    <ChannelLifetime>300000</ChannelLifetime>
    <SecurityTokenLifetime>3600000</SecurityTokenLifetime>
  </TransportQuotas>
  <ServerConfiguration>
    <BaseAddresses>
      <ua:String>opc.tcp://localhost:26543/RoboBar.TestServer</ua:String>
     </BaseAddresses>
    <SecurityPolicies>
      <ServerSecurityPolicy>
        <SecurityMode>None_1</SecurityMode>
        <SecurityPolicyUri>http://opcfoundation.org/UA/SecurityPolicy#None</SecurityPolicyUri>
        <SecurityLevel>0</SecurityLevel>
      </ServerSecurityPolicy>
      <ServerSecurityPolicy>
        <SecurityMode>SignAndEncrypt_3</SecurityMode>
        <SecurityPolicyUri>http://opcfoundation.org/UA/SecurityPolicy#Basic256</SecurityPolicyUri>
        <SecurityLevel>5</SecurityLevel>
      </ServerSecurityPolicy>
      <ServerSecurityPolicy>
        <SecurityMode>SignAndEncrypt_3</SecurityMode>
        <SecurityPolicyUri>http://opcfoundation.org/UA/SecurityPolicy#Basic256Sha256</SecurityPolicyUri>
        <SecurityLevel>6</SecurityLevel>
      </ServerSecurityPolicy>
    </SecurityPolicies>

    <MinRequestThreadCount>5</MinRequestThreadCount>
    <MaxRequestThreadCount>100</MaxRequestThreadCount>
    <MaxQueuedRequestCount>2000</MaxQueuedRequestCount>
    
    <!-- The SDK expects the server to support the same set of user tokens for every endpoint. -->
    <UserTokenPolicies>

      <!-- Allows anonymous users -->
      <ua:UserTokenPolicy>
        <ua:TokenType>Anonymous_0</ua:TokenType>
        <ua:SecurityPolicyUri>http://opcfoundation.org/UA/SecurityPolicy#None</ua:SecurityPolicyUri>
      </ua:UserTokenPolicy>     

      <!-- Allows username/password -->
      <!-- passwords must be encrypted - this specifies what algorithm to use -->
      <!--<ua:UserTokenPolicy>
        <ua:TokenType>UserName_1</ua:TokenType>        
        <ua:SecurityPolicyUri>http://opcfoundation.org/UA/SecurityPolicy#Basic256</ua:SecurityPolicyUri>
      </ua:UserTokenPolicy>-->
    
    </UserTokenPolicies>
    
    <DiagnosticsEnabled>true</DiagnosticsEnabled>
    <MaxSessionCount>100</MaxSessionCount>
    <MinSessionTimeout>10000</MinSessionTimeout>
    <MaxSessionTimeout>3600000</MaxSessionTimeout>
    <MaxBrowseContinuationPoints>10</MaxBrowseContinuationPoints>
    <MaxQueryContinuationPoints>10</MaxQueryContinuationPoints>
    <MaxHistoryContinuationPoints>100</MaxHistoryContinuationPoints>
    <MaxRequestAge>600000</MaxRequestAge>
    <MinPublishingInterval>100</MinPublishingInterval>
    <MaxPublishingInterval>3600000</MaxPublishingInterval>
    <PublishingResolution>50</PublishingResolution>
    <MaxSubscriptionLifetime>3600000</MaxSubscriptionLifetime>
    <MaxMessageQueueSize>100</MaxMessageQueueSize>
    <MaxNotificationQueueSize>100</MaxNotificationQueueSize>
    <MaxNotificationsPerPublish>1000</MaxNotificationsPerPublish>
    <MinMetadataSamplingInterval>1000</MinMetadataSamplingInterval>
    <AvailableSamplingRates>
      <SamplingRateGroup>
        <Start>5</Start>
        <Increment>5</Increment>
        <Count>20</Count>
      </SamplingRateGroup>
      <SamplingRateGroup>
        <Start>100</Start>
        <Increment>100</Increment>
        <Count>4</Count>
      </SamplingRateGroup>
      <SamplingRateGroup>
        <Start>500</Start>
        <Increment>250</Increment>
        <Count>2</Count>
      </SamplingRateGroup>
      <SamplingRateGroup>
        <Start>1000</Start>
        <Increment>500</Increment>
        <Count>20</Count>
      </SamplingRateGroup>
    </AvailableSamplingRates>
    <MaxRegistrationInterval>0</MaxRegistrationInterval>
    <NodeManagerSaveFile>RoboBar.TestServer.nodes.xml</NodeManagerSaveFile>
  </ServerConfiguration>

  <TraceConfiguration>
    <OutputFilePath>Logs\RoboBar.TestServer.log.txt</OutputFilePath>
    <DeleteOnLoad>true</DeleteOnLoad>
    <!-- Show Only Errors -->
    <!-- <TraceMasks>1</TraceMasks> -->
    <!-- Show Only Security and Errors -->
    <!-- <TraceMasks>513</TraceMasks> -->
    <!-- Show Only Security, Errors and Trace -->
    <!-- <TraceMasks>515</TraceMasks> -->
    <!-- Show Only Security, COM Calls, Errors and Trace -->
    <!-- <TraceMasks>771</TraceMasks> -->
    <!-- Show Only Security, Service Calls, Errors and Trace -->
    <!-- <TraceMasks>523</TraceMasks> -->
    <!-- Show Only Security, ServiceResultExceptions, Errors and Trace -->
    <!-- <TraceMasks>519</TraceMasks> -->
  </TraceConfiguration>
  
</ApplicationConfiguration>
```

Method that I use to start server (it runs in BackgroundWorker)

```
private void InitServer()
        {
            ApplicationInstance app = new ApplicationInstance
            {
                ApplicationName = "RoboBar.TestServer",
                ApplicationType = ApplicationType.Server,
                ConfigSectionName = "RoboBar.TestServer"
            };

            try
            {
                var configuration = app.LoadApplicationConfiguration(false);
                var certificate = app.CheckApplicationInstanceCertificate(false, 0);
                certificate.Wait();
                var certOK = certificate.Result;
                if (!certOK)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Application instance certificate invalid!");
                }

                var startServer = app.Start(new RoboBarServer());
                startServer.Wait();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string text = "Exception: " + ex.Message;
                if (ex.InnerException != null)
                {
                    text += "\r\nInner exception: ";
                    text += ex.InnerException.Message;
                }
                MessageBox.Show(text, app.ApplicationName);
            }

            Server = app.Server as StandardServer;
            Configuration = app.ApplicationConfiguration;
        }
```

What can I try next?

Comment: The validation of the certificate (CheckApplicationInstanceCertificate) is done by a virtual connection.  So as part of the connection TLS (which is used for authentication) is performed.  Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and check version of TLS.  Five years ago the industry decided to eliminate TLS 1.0/1.1 due to security issues and require clients to use TLS 1.2/1.3.  In June this year Microsoft pushed a security update disabling TLS on servers.  So this could explain why your code suddenly stopped working.

Comment: See my responses at following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64375532/ssis-c-sharp-http-getasync-not-waiting-for-the-response#comment113835214_64375532

Comment: thanks for ur comment. i have solved this problem with DigiCertUtil app a then restarting computer